# How could I get the matched nested items in array

Tags: mongodb

How could I get the matched nested items in array

I want to return the matched items in nested array.

For example, I want to filter out the records that contain `"A428 ","A429 "` in their **items**

How could I get it ?

## Query

```
pipeline_work = [
  { '$match': 'records.items': '$in': ["A428 ","A429 "])}
]
  cur = db[source_collection].runCommand('aggregate',pipeline: pipeline_work , allowDiskUse: true)
```

## Sample Document

```
  {
    "_id": "0007db2dac8d6482ec60c228b700c3ec",
    "records": [
      {
        "APPL_DATE": new Date("1996-03-19T08:00:00+0800"),
        "FUNC_DATE": new Date("1996-02-27T08:00:00+0800"),
        "items": [
          "A428 ",
          "     ",
          "     "
        ]
      },
      {
        "APPL_DATE": new Date("1996-03-19T08:00:00+0800"),
        "FUNC_DATE": new Date("1996-02-27T08:00:00+0800"),
        "items": [
          "A429 ",
          "     ",
          "     "
        ]
      },
      {
        "APPL_DATE": new Date("1996-04-15T08:00:00+0800"),
        "FUNC_DATE": new Date("1996-03-18T08:00:00+0800"),
        "items": [
          "A180 ",
          "     ",
          "     "
        ]
      }]
```

## Expected result

```
  "_id": "0007db2dac8d6482ec60c228b700c3ec",
  "records": [
    {
      "APPL_DATE": new Date("1996-03-19T08:00:00+0800"),
      "FUNC_DATE": new Date("1996-02-27T08:00:00+0800"),
      "items": [
        "A428 ",
        "     ",
        "     "
      ]
    },
    {
      "APPL_DATE": new Date("1996-03-19T08:00:00+0800"),
      "FUNC_DATE": new Date("1996-02-27T08:00:00+0800"),
      "items": [
        "A429 ",
        "     ",
        "     "
      ]
    }]
```

## Failed with {"errmsg":"exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.","code":16435,"ok":0}

```
pipeline_work = [
  {
    "$unwind": "$records",
    "$match": {
      "records.items": {
        "$in": ["A428 ", "A429 "]
      }
    },
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "records": {
        "$push": "$records"
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$limit': 1
  }
];
```

Comment: [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `records` array first and then `match`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `records` and then `match` elements like following:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$records"
}, {
    "$match": {
    "records.items": {
        "$in": ["A428 ", "A429 "]
    }
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "records": {
        "$push": "$records"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Hi your solution will failed with ` A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.`

Comment: @newBike No, It will give you expected output. Did you tried it? This exception will occur only if you try to push anything outside `_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below query :

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
   {"$unwind" : "$records"},
   {"$unwind" : "$records.items"},
   {"$match" : {"records.items" : {"$in" : [ "A428 ","A429 "] } } },
   {"$group" : { "_id" :  { "id" : "$_id" , "app_date" : "$records.APPL_DATE" , 
    "fun_date" : "$records.FUNC_DATE"} , 
    "records_temp" : { "APPL_DATE" : { "$first" :"$records.APPL_DATE" },
    "FUNC_DATE" : { "$first" : "$records.FUNC_DATE" } ,
    "items" : {"$push" : "$records.items"} } },
  {"$group" : { "_id" : "$_id.id", "records" : { "$push" : "$records_temp" } } }
 ]);
```